# IntelliJ IDEA 13 Scala Incremental Compiler

Tags: macos, scala, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-13

I get the following exception when running IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 13 using the inbuilt incremental Scala compiler. I'm running the IDE on the 1.7 JVM. Using the 1.7 JDK to run the Scala server. The server starts fine but when I try to build the project with Run compile server checked in the Scala IDE preferences I see;

Running on Mac.

```
Error:scalac: Error: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.TraceEvent; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 738038529458485035, local class serialVersionUID = -7195951195672334439
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.TraceEvent; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 738038529458485035, local class serialVersionUID = -7195951195672334439
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:617)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1622)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1517)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1771)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1350)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:370)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Event$.fromBytes(Event.scala:25)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.handle(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:50)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.handle(RemoteServer.scala:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:27)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:26)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.using(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.using(RemoteServer.scala:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:26)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:23)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.using(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.using(RemoteServer.scala:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:23)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$$anonfun$send$1.apply(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.using(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:35)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.using(RemoteServer.scala:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteResourceOwner$class.send(RemoteResourceOwner.scala:22)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.send(RemoteServer.scala:12)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.RemoteServer.compile(RemoteServer.scala:20)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderDelegate$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ScalaBuilderDelegate.scala:45)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderDelegate$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ScalaBuilderDelegate.scala:39)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.map(Either.scala:535)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderDelegate$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ScalaBuilderDelegate.scala:39)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderDelegate$$anonfun$compile$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(ScalaBuilderDelegate.scala:38)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:522)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderDelegate$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(ScalaBuilderDelegate.scala:38)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderDelegate$$anonfun$compile$1.apply(ScalaBuilderDelegate.scala:37)
    at scala.util.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:522)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilderDelegate.compile(ScalaBuilderDelegate.scala:37)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.IdeaIncrementalBuilder$.build(IdeaIncrementalBuilder.scala:47)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.ScalaBuilder.build(ScalaBuilder.scala:29)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runModuleLevelBuilders(IncProjectBuilder.java:1106)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:814)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:862)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:777)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:600)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:352)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:184)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:129)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:224)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:133)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:41)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-7435